# Google play Linked App:An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: android

When i try to linked app, It happen in STEP 2: AUTHORIZE YOUR APP .
The Google play help section says a blank box means I have not accepted the T & C,I just visit cloud.google.com and click my project and accepted the T & C.But doesn't work.
By the way, I create a new different project,Did it influencea Linked app work?
Am i missing something?